# @ManagedBean not initialize with jsf + spring boot

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-boot

I am trying to build simple backoffice app. I choose to use jsf(PrimeFaces) because of rich ui components that doesn't require any Front end developer(The look doesn't matter it just to perform actions on our main system).

The issue that i have is that @ManagedBean doesn't work at all.. It just doesn't consider it and does not perform auto scan.

In case i put the bean in faces-config.xml it works.. Anyone has an idea?

The config file is:

```
@Bean
public FacesServlet facesServlet() {
    return new FacesServlet();
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean facesServletRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(facesServlet(), new String[] { "*.xhtml", "*.jsf" });
    registration.setName("FacesServlet");
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return registration;
}

@Configuration
static class ConfigureJSFContextParameters implements ServletContextInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", "true");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX", ".xhtml");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
        servletContext.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
    }
}

@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener> jsfConfigureListener() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener>(new ConfigureListener());
}
```

Comment: Did you use the correct `@ManagedBean`? And JSF will only work with a war packaging (at least that is what I think) and not jar packaging.

Comment: Basically i tried also package war. But this is not the problem. When i run it throw eclipse it doesnt work.. only if i define beans under faces config